# JavaScript setting left and top positions dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem. I would like the set to and left position of the element be implemented , which I haven't been able to work it out. Anyone with suggestion of a working solution thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

//lets assign a value to a variable, but in my case the value is obtained from different part but that has no problem.
//Note in real case this value changes.
var number = 4;


//we create a function to count the top and left dimensions
//Note the values given are exactly as I want. the param given is number of current rect and second is total rect to be drawn.
 function dim(i,a)
 {
  var top = '';
  if((i%2)==0){top = 0;}
  else if ((i%2)==1){top = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight)*1/3)/2; top = Math.floor(top);}
  //We have gotten the top value if odd 0px if even halfway our container.
  //Now for the left.
  var y = (((a/2)+1)-i);
  y = y*(-1);
  var W = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var left = Math.floor(((W/2)+(30*y)));
  //alert(top+' , '+left);
  return ([top,left]);
 }
 function draw()
 {
  //This is the main function.
  for (i = 1; i <= number; i++ )
  {
   
   
  var cd = document.createElement('div');
  var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
  cd.appendChild(node);
  cd.style.width = '30px';
  cd.style.background = 'rgb('+10*i+','+20*i+','+15*i+')';
  cd.setAttribute ('position','relative');
  var x = Math.floor(((document.documentElement.clientHeight)*1/3)/2);
  cd.style.height = x+'px';
  cd.className = 'rect'+i;
  var di = dim(i,number);
  cd.style.top = di[0]+'px';
  cd.style.left = di[1]+'px';
  document.body.appendChild (cd);
  }
 }
 draw();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I do not want it to appear on the same line with no alignment of top and left. thanks.

Comment: try cd.style.position = "relative"

Comment: Not working. but thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry I had put it in the wrong part. It worked. Thanks.